# Problema para recibir datos de un formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Por alguna razon cuando trato de recibir la informacion de un formulario getElementById no responde, en vez de recibir datos la variable se queda en null y luego me da un error cuando uso el addEventListener, a continuacion el codigo en JS.

```
"use strict";

let formulario = document.getElementById('envio');//Aqui queda en null

console.log(formulario);
formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Me diste un click');
});
```

Y aqui esta el formulario en html.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <div class="Centrar">
                <form id="formulario" method="post" name="ingresar" class="formularios" style="width: 300px;">
                        <h3>Formulario</h3><br>
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;  flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
                                <label>Nombre</label for="name"><input type="text" name="name" required style="margin: 10px; width: 150px;">
                                <label>Apellido</label for="surname"><input type="text" name="surname" required style="margin: 10px; width: 150px;">
                                <label style="position:relative;">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" required style="margin: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; width: 150px;">
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div style="position:relative; top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <label style='margin-top: 15px;'>Contraseña</label><br><input type="password" name="password" required style="margin: 10px; width: 150px;"><br>
                                <label>Repetir Contraseña</label><br>
                                <input type="password" name="passwordR" required style="margin: 10px; width: 150px;"><br>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class='button' style='padding: 3px 10px; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;'>
                </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el error que me da la consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Algo debe estar mal con el formulario.

Comment: Hola Firiel, prueba con: **window.onload = function() {** coloca tu código dentro, de esa forma se ejecuta después de cargar la página, que es la razón del null".

Comment: ¿con cambiar al `id` del formulario (`document.getElementById('formulario');`) se soluciona? ¿Qué nuevo error tienes?...

Comment: Hola de nuevo, tambien puedes solucionarlo, colocando **<script src="js/app.js"></script>** al final del "body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ningún elemento del HTML tiene el id `envio`. Cambia el id del formulario a `envio` o cambia

```
let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
```

---

EDIT: la etiqueta `<script>` deberia ir al final del `body` para que el script se cargue cuando ya se haya renderizado la página. Puede estar pasando que cuando haces el `getElementById`, el formulario todavía no se haya renderizado.

Mueve la etiqueta `<script>` así:

```
<body>
    <div class="Centrar">
    ...
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Si aún así tienes problemas, prueba a poner todo el código de tu script en un evento que espera a que se cargue la página:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');//Aqui queda en null

    console.log(formulario);
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Me diste un click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :)

Comment: Si esto ha resuelto tu problema, agradezco que lo marques como respuesta. Asi puede serle de utilidad a quienes lo vean en el futuro.

Comment: También puedes agregar el atributo [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) si el script se encuentra en otro archivo para que se ejecute una vez cargado el DOM.